# Sencha application in a Facebook iFrame gets a "Cannot POST /"

Tags: facebook, node.js, amazon-ec2, sencha-touch, socket.io

I have a Sencha Touch application using Node.js and Socket.io running on Amazon EC2 (micro instance). I want to make it available on Facebook, in a Facebook Canvas, aka an HTML iFrame.

I get a blank page with `Cannot POST /`

The iframe is here (when I do "Open frame in new window" it opens the app). I have no idea what to do here… why do I get a `POST /`?

I use the Facebook Javascript SDK in the app, but commenting the code doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Before anything else, try debugging with Firefox 4. Safari is reluctant to accept third party cookies. Then, you should inspect what is responsible for `POST`ing something to your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [POST for Canvas](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/canvas/post/) may be causing your issues.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up catching the POST parameters in node to redirect users to the authentication page like so:

`server.post('/', function(request, response){
 response.redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID&redirect_uri=CANVAS_URL");
});`

Comment: The link throws 404. Any solution for question?

Answer (score 2):

We solved a similar problem recently by changing this line:

```
app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
```

to this

```
app.all('/home', function(request, response) {
```

Comment: That's probably because it's actually node w/ express